# Unable to inject remote bean on JBoss EAP 7: ClassCastException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, javabeans, ejb-3.1

I have two maven Java applications running on two difference Jboss EAP 7 instances, lets name them Client-Application , Server-Application.

I want to do a remote injection on the Client-Application, injecting a bean from the Server-Application.

My structure is following:

**Client-Application**

I have added the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

My main class and interface on this application looks like following:

```
public void remoteInjectionTest() {
    try {


        final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        jndiProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost");
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");


        Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        String jndi = "java:global/Server-Application/ServiceBean!test.package.ServiceBeanInterface";
        serviceInterface = (ServiceBeanInterface) context.lookup(jndi);

        return serviceInterface.getHelloString();
    } catch (NamingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and the Interface:

```
public interface ServiceBeanInterface {

    public String getHelloString();

}
```

**Server-Application**
This section shows how my server-application looks like:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(ServiceBeanInterface.class)
public class ServiceBean implements ServiceBeanInterface {

    @Override
    public String getHelloString() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

I tried also to add a @Remote on the server-applications Interface but again i had no success.

```
@Remote
 public interface ServiceBeanInterface {
    public String getHelloString();
 }
```

Any suggestions?

The error i am getting is:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118
>   cannot be cast to test.package.ServiceBeanInterface

Comment: The problem to my implementation was the packaging after all. Interfaces on both projects must have the same packaging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your **Client-Application** is also *deployed* on your JBoss EAP 7 instance, then the solution is far simpler than you think.

I set up a test project that creates four artifacts:

- serverapi - contains the `ServiceBeanInterface`
- serverejb - contains the `ServiceBean`
- serverapp - EAR containing `serverejb` and `serverapi`
- clientapp - WAR containing a servlet (shown below) and `serverapi` in it's WEB-INF/lib directory

The test servlet looks like:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/")
public class Client extends HttpServlet {

    // Inject remote stub
    @EJB(lookup="java:global/serverapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/serverejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ServiceBean!com.stackoverflow.p42618757.api.ServiceBeanInterface")
    private ServiceBeanInterface serviceBeanInterface;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().write(serviceBeanInterface.getHelloString());
    }

}
```

The `serverapp` and `clientapp` are deployed to the server.

Hitting http://localhost:8080/clientapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ yields the expected `Hello`.

No old fashioned JNDI lookups needed.

However, if you really want to do a JNDI lookup, then you just need:

```
 Context initialContext = new InitialContext(); // no props needed in the same server instance
 ServiceBeanInterface serviceBeanInterface
     = (ServiceBeanInterface)initialContext.lookup("java:global/serverapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/serverejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ServiceBean!com.stackoverflow.p42618757.api.ServiceBeanInterface");
```

A demo example can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/sfcoy/app42618757).

Comment: No, they will run on a different instance. So i need to find why my lookup does not work. I am missing one step in your answer. Containing the serverapi in the lib directory . How ? Create a jar of the Interface and add it with maven to the build path ?

Comment: I've found that a separate API jar works best for remote EJB interfaces. Now, your first sentence says "... two maven Java applications running o the same Jboss EAP 7 instance ...", so if this is not the case please update your question with the correct details. For example, is the client a standalone java application?

Comment: I am somehow stuck . I created a new maven project containing just the Interface (ServiceBeanInterface ) and added it as a maven dependency to the Client-Application. I still get the classcast exception.  I read in other people trying to do something similar that they could fix it by removing the @Remote annotation or fixing the naming. It looks that this is not the same case with my project.

Comment: I tried to test under the same instance with @EJB("java:global/Server-Application/ServiceBean!test.package.ServiceBeanInterface") annotation but this gives me following exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance

Comment: Are you using two EAR files, or an EAR and a WAR?

Comment: I was testing with 2 seperate wars on the same instance . I found out about the requirement a bit later that those should run on different instances. I am trying to test your second answer. I got a question though. Can't i just copy the interface class in my client app ? Do i have to provide it as a dependency in order to have it in the class path as an external library ? Thank you Steve.

Comment: Actually, the JNDI name looks like Server-Application is a WAR?

Comment: Yes. Server-application is a war. Client-application is also a war. I took the jndi name (As seen in my code) from the jboss logs. It writes in the logs the JNDI name for the ServiceBean in the Server-Application.  If i try another jndi name i get a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException . I hope i understood the question correct.

Comment: I tried copying the interface and that worked. I then changed the package that the interface was in on the client side and got the same WFLYEE0042 error that you did. Therefore if you copy the interface it must be a binary match for the server side version. That's why it's safer to have it in it's own jar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137442/discussion-between-steve-c-and-stephan).

Comment: Could you give me please a few details how you made it work ? I tried to provide the interface with two different ways in my client application . 1) Maven dependency with a systemScope jar (the jar was the interface) . 2) Created a maven project just with the interface and added this maven project as a dependency to my client-application. In both cases i was still getting the classcast exception .

Answer (score 1):

There is extensive documentation for doing instance-to-instance remote EJB calls on the JBoss documentation site at [EJB invocations from a remote server instance](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance).

The configuration may look a little complicated but that is primarily for security reasons. The code side is still relatively simple.

I recommend that you refer to this and then ask a new question if you still have problems.